# Chrome manifest trailing slash matches

Tags: regex, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I'm using this pattern to match a `host` but it is not working with the `/` at the end of the url.

```
 "matches": ["*://website.com/browse", "*://www.website.com/browse"]
```

do I have to write something like this to make it work?

```
 "matches": ["*://website.com/browse", "*://www.website.com/browse", "*://www.website.com/browse/"]
```

I did not get at all how does this pattern matching works since is not working like a regex

Comment: `*://website.com/browse` is a wildcard, not a regex pattern.

Comment: that's what I'm saying :) I'm trying to figure out how to write one path instead of four..

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns

Comment: Really? In your mind I did not check it out? I asked because I did not understand the docs.

Comment: Look at the `http://*/foo*` example in Rob W's link.

Answer (score -1):

`https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?website.com\/browse\/?`

This regex should be flexible enough to match any of your inputs. The `?` operator for regex allows the preceding match to be optional - if you aren't sure whether there will be a `/` at the end of the regex, adding a `?` lets it match either way. This also goes for `(?:www.)` - the regex makes that optional, too.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/y1CCgC/1)